# Akward delay to connect Apache's proxy request to a node.js App

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, node.js

In my Ubuntu Server 10.04 I'm running an example node.js app:

```
var http = require("http");

function onRequest(request, response) {

        console.log("Request received.");
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();

}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);
```

It simply listens to requests on port 3000, log in console this request and send to the client an HTTP *"Hello World"*

The goal was to make this app coexists with Apache2. So after some research I edited the default file (*/etc/apache2/sites-available/default*) this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin haj@myserver.com
        ServerName dev.myserver.com

        <Location /node>

                ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000/
                ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/

        </Location>

        <Proxy>
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        DocumentRoot /home/haj/www/http_home

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/haj/www/http_home/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /home/haj/www/log/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /home/haj/www/log/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

So, when a user makes a call to `http://dev.myserver.com/node` or `http://dev.myserver.com/node/`, Apache proxies the request, Node.js makes the processing, and the user gets back a "Hello World".

There is just one problem: It takes some time to, Let's call it 'Load' the Proxy, in other words, I get these messages at the browser:

```
<503 Service Temporarily Unavailable>

Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at dev.neosource.cl Port 80
```

Besides, error.log tells me:

```
[Thu Apr 21 01:02:10 2011] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (127.0.0.1)
[Thu Apr 21 01:02:10 2011] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (127.0.0.1)
[Thu Apr 21 01:02:10 2011] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (127.0.0.1)
```

Then suddenly, It Works, just like that. No number of requests, no time, no pattern at all.

In layman's terms, the service has to *'load'*, That's the impression it gives, but, I would like to know if there is a way to minimize this delay. Or I would rather know *What* is wrong with the configuration noted above.

**Edit 1**: After modifying LogLevel to debug, during one of these delays I get this per request:

```
[Thu Apr 21 02:30:40 2011] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(56): proxy: HTTP: canonicalising URL //127.0.0.1:3000/
[Thu Apr 21 02:30:40 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1494): [client 200.xxx.yyy.zzz] proxy: http: found worker http://127.0.0.1:3000/ for http://127.0.0.1:3000/
[Thu Apr 21 02:30:40 2011] [debug] mod_proxy.c(993): Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Thu Apr 21 02:30:40 2011] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1940): proxy: HTTP: serving URL http://127.0.0.1:3000/
[Thu Apr 21 02:30:40 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1937): proxy: HTTP: retrying the worker for (127.0.0.1)
[Thu Apr 21 02:30:40 2011] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (127.0.0.1)
[Thu Apr 21 02:30:40 2011] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 200.xxx.yyy.zzz] Zlib: Compressed 405 to 273 : URL /node
```

...and when it is right again:

```
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(56): proxy: HTTP: canonicalising URL //127.0.0.1:3000/
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1494): [client 200.xxx.yyy.zzz] proxy: http: found worker http://127.0.0.1:3000/ for http://127.0.0.1:3000/
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] mod_proxy.c(993): Running scheme http handler (attempt 0)
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1940): proxy: HTTP: serving URL http://127.0.0.1:3000/
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(1999): proxy: HTTP: has acquired connection for (127.0.0.1)
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2055): proxy: connecting http://127.0.0.1:3000/ to 127.0.0.1:3000
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2153): proxy: connected / to 127.0.0.1:3000
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2244): proxy: HTTP: backend socket is disconnected.
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2308): proxy: HTTP: fam 2 socket created to connect to 127.0.0.1
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2414): proxy: HTTP: connection complete to 127.0.0.1:3000 (127.0.0.1)
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1723): proxy: start body send
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 200.xxx.yyy.zzz] Zlib: Compressed 11 to 13 : URL /node
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] mod_proxy_http.c(1816): proxy: end body send
[Thu Apr 21 02:35:16 2011] [debug] proxy_util.c(2017): proxy: HTTP: has released connection for (127.0.0.1)
```

Comment: To the moderators: I'm not sure if this is a stackoverflow question or a serverfault question, so I posted both sites.

Comment: Cross posting is a bad idea unless you don't get an answer, then be sure to cross link between them too! If you post at wrong place the moderators will help migrate it to the right place, but please don't just duplicate our efforts from the start!

Comment: Sorry @Caleb, Beginner's Mistake. Won't happen again.

Comment: No worries, this is a learn as you go place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing `LogLevel` to `debug` will give you more information in error.log. Please do so and post the results. Without that information, I have a guess that changing your ProxyPass line to `ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/ retry=0` might help. In general, the [Apache mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) has more details on the parameters available to you.

Comment: Thanks @justarobert, Now I'm experience an "Inverse Murphy", because I'm trying to replicate the error, and everything goes fine! I bet that in production I will have this situation again... As soon as I have the data, I'm going to fill it here. Thanks Again.

Comment: That figures! Make sure not to use `LogLevel debug` in production.

Comment: LOL. I've just edited my question.

Comment: The Apache logs indicate that your node.js process isn't responding to the proxied requests during the delays. Do you get anything from your node.js logs at that time? Can you visit the node.js server in your browser directly when Apache is giving you a delay? Consider using `ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000/ retry=0 timeout=10`, just to make the timeout explicit. Also, see discussion at http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2037328 for why you might want not to put Apache in front of node.js.

Answer (score 2):

Digging this up. I had this issue on CentOS with SELinux enable. All I needed to do is to allow httpd to make network connections:

`/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1`

(and restart httpd)